# Non top-level package import

Tags: julia

As far as I have been using Julia, I have been under the impression that package imports could only be done at the top-level. However, has anyone found a tricky/unofficial method of making the below work? Basically, I want to conditionally import the package. If the package is installed, I want to import it, however if it is not installed, I don't want to include it (so Julia then won't automatically install it).

`if Pkg.installed("my_package") != Void
        import my_package
    else
        ## DO NOT IMPORT my_package
    end`

I understand this to be impossible, but considering how quickly Julia is changing, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a new method of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said `Pkg.installed()` will return a Void type if the package is not installed.So you can create a function to do this check for you:

```
function load_if_installed(package_name)
  if typeof(Pkg.installed(package_name)) == Void
    println("package is not installed")
  else
    # load in package after parsing command
    eval(parse("using $package_name"))
 end
end

load_if_installed("PyPlot")
> 
load_if_installed("AWS")
> package is not installed
```

Tried this with Julia 0.4.5 AWS not installed and PyPlot installed.
Check the [metaprogramming section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/metaprogramming/) for info on how the `eval()` and `parse()` functions work.

Comment: Neat trick; I use metaprogramming all the time but I hadn't thought about wrapping the statement in a `parse` and then taking advantage of the global scope of `eval` to get it to work! Thanks!